# Как преобразовать object в формат времени для столбца?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо преобразовать строку в формате 'object' 10:22:55 в формат 'time'.

Попробовал в таком формате:

```py
data['start_time'] = datetime.time.strptime(data['start_time']).isoformat()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Pandas и в NumPy не существует типа данных `time` - есть только `datetime64`, который **обязан содержать компоненту даты**, и `timedelta64`.

Вот пример преобразования в `timedelta64`:

```
In [34]: df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["10:22:55"]})

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
          x
0  10:22:55

In [36]: df.dtypes
Out[36]:
x    object
dtype: object
```

---

```
In [37]: df["timedelta"] = pd.to_timedelta(df["x"])

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
          x       timedelta
0  10:22:55 0 days 10:22:55

In [39]: df.dtypes
Out[39]:
x                     object
timedelta    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: Попробовал data['start_time_x'] = pd.to_timedelta(data['start_time']), но вышла ошибка TypeError: Expected unicode, got datetime.time
ValueError: Invalid type for timedelta scalar: <class 'datetime.time'>
Работаю в google colab

Comment: Получилось в таком варианте ```data["start_time_x"] = pd.to_timedelta(data['start_time'].astype(str))```, но  формат отображения 0 days 23:27:41